# Pycharm – "Unfortunately 'Reformat file' is currently not available for batch mode"

Tags: python-2.7, pycharm

Pycharm is telling me that I have too many leading #'s for block comments, so I am trying to use alt+enter to reformat. But I get the error: "Unfortunately 'Reformat file' is currently not available for batch mode". What's going on and what's batch mode?

Comment: I'm not sure what is going on behind the scenes but I have found a workaround for it. Simply press `Ctrl + Shift + Alt + L` to bring up the reformat file dialog.

Comment: @mauna, yes, but clicking "run" on the dialog doesn't perform the reformat. Any other suggestions?

Comment: @mauna, it works! Thank you.